# Node.js SparkPost Not able to send attachments via transmission API

Tags: node.js, sparkpost

I am using Node.js and Axios to send emails via SparkPost Transmission API.
I am able to get the emails successfully, however, I am not able to get the attachments.
The Spark Post documentation says that we can get the attachment files using **content.attachments**, but still I was able to get the mail, but did not receive the expected attachment file.

Attached below is the code snippet:

```
  static async sendModelReport() {
const data = {
  content: {
    template_id: process.env.emailTemplate,
    attachments: [{
      name: 'report.pdf',
      type: 'application/pdf',
      data: 'Q29uZ3JhdHVsYXRpb25zLCB5b3UgY2FuIGJhc2U2NCBkZWNvZGUh',
    }], // taken from example and tried others too.
  },
  recipients: [{
    address: process.env.internalEmail,
    substitution_data: {
      environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    },
  }],
};
try {
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.emailServiceBaseURL}/api/v1/transmissions`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: process.env.emailServiceKey,
    },
  });
  if (response.data && response.data.results) {
    return response.data.results;
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data);
  throw new Error(`Email Service Error: ${error.message}`);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It turns out spark post doesn't support sending attachements with stored templates. One work around is that we can get the stored template and use that template html to send mail.

```
async sendModelReport() {
// Update code start
const getTemplateResponse = await retrieveTemplate(templateId);
getTemplateResponse.content.attachments = attachments: [{
      name: 'report.pdf',
      type: 'application/pdf',
      data: 'Q29uZ3JhdHVsYXRpb25zLCB5b3UgY2FuIGJhc2U2NCBkZWNvZGUh',
    }];
const data = {
  content: getTemplateResponse.content,
// Updated code end
  recipients: [{
    address: process.env.internalEmail,
    substitution_data: {
      environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    },
  }],
};
try {
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.emailServiceBaseURL}/api/v1/transmissions`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: process.env.emailServiceKey,
    },
  });
  if (response.data && response.data.results) {
    return response.data.results;
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data);
  throw new Error(`Email Service Error: ${error.response.data}`);
}
```

}